# Webpack doesn't process CSS background image

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

[The following](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lrp8wvo/) Webpack configuration does not allow me to process CSS images as the background property:

```css
background: url('./hero.jpg') no-repeat right;
```

results in the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/Contact/Contact.style.scss (./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/app/components/Contact/Contact.style.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve 'assets/img/section/hero.jpg' in
```

What URL should I pass ass the CSS property so that Webpack would catch it?

**Dist directory screenshot:**

[image: dist]

**Public directory screenshot:**

[image: public]

Comment: Are you using file-loader in your webpack config file?

Comment: @Sandsten yes, please refer to the Webpack configuration

Comment: Whops. Missed the link

Comment: Never used the Copy plugin, but reading here https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/ it seems like you have to explicitly include the content in the "from" variable. Does this make a difference for you?   
{ from: './src/public/assets/images/*.png', to: 'assets/img/' }
there's a trailing "/" in the "to" variable as well

Comment: @Sandsten ERROR in unable to locate '[path]/src/public/assets/images/*.png' glob

Comment: Not sure, but I would recommend reading through the documentation for the plugin.Then debug whether or not your import path is wrong in the CSS, or if the image is in the given folder or not.

Comment: And in my previous suggestion i typed .png when it should've been .jpg

Comment: @Sandsten what would be your implementation here?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved myself. Please reach for helping with the solution:

```js
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '/assets/img'),
    outputPath: 'assets/img',
    name: '[name].[ext]'
  }
}
```